# If $\int_\mathbb{R} |f_n| \le \frac{1}{n^2}$, then $f_n \to 0 \lambda$-a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Assume that $f_n : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions such that $\int_\mathbb{R} |f_n|d\lambda \le \frac{1}{n^2}$. 
Show that $f_n \to 0 \lambda$-a.e.

My attempt :

Choose $\delta>0$ and denote the set $E^\delta_n = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : |f_n|\ge \delta\}$ 
$$\frac{1}{n^2}\ge\int_\mathbb{R} |f_n|d\lambda \ge  \int _{E^\delta_n}|f_n|d\lambda \ge \delta \lambda\Big(\{x\in \mathbb{R} : |f_n|\ge \delta\}\Big)$$
taking limit as $n\to\infty$;
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(E^\delta_n) =\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda\Big(\{x\in \mathbb{R} : |f_n|\ge \delta\}\Big)=0$$
so $f_n \to 0 \lambda$-a.e

Comment: All of a sudden I just realized that your proof might not go through. For you just proved that $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ in measure, this is weaker than a.e. pointwise convergence.

Comment: oh, right. I thought it asks for convergence in measure. but it is for almost every where.

Comment: Your proof is not correct. What you proved is convergence in measure.Almost everywhere convergence usually requires more care than  convergence in measure.

Comment: @stat_yale what do you want? kabo explained why your proof fails, and user284331 gave a correct proof below, and replied to your comment (a while ago) sufficiently

Comment: you're right, however  I wondered to see if there is any other way as well to prove it. also, I still did not get the provided answer completely because what I replied below I understood is also wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, but somehow it is more complicated:

Let $S$ be the set defined by

\begin{align*}
S=\bigcap_{N}\bigcup_{m}\bigcap_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|f_{n}(x)|<\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}.
\end{align*}

This set collects those points $x$ such that $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow 0$. We are to show that $\lambda(S^{c})=0$, this means that $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow 0$ $\lambda$-a.e.

The set $S^{c}$ can be written as 
\begin{align*}
S^{c}=\bigcup_{N}\bigcap_{m}\bigcup_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}
\end{align*}

Fix $N$ and $m$, then for all $n\geq m$, we have
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{N}\lambda\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}：|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}\right)\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_{n}|d\lambda\leq\dfrac{1}{n^{2}},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{N}\lambda\left(\bigcup_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}：|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}\right)\leq\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{n\geq m}\lambda\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}：|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}\right)\leq\sum_{n\geq m}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}},
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\lambda\left(\bigcap_{m}\bigcup_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}：|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}\right)\leq\lambda\left(\bigcup_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}：|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}\right)\leq N\sum_{n\geq m}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Since this is valid for all $m=1,2,...$ and we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq m}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$, it follows that 
\begin{align*}
\lambda\left(\bigcap_{m}\bigcup_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}：|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}\right)=0.
\end{align*}
Note that this is also valid for all $N=1,2,...$, it follows that 
\begin{align*}
\lambda(S^{c})\leq\sum_{N}\lambda\left(\bigcap_{m}\bigcup_{n\geq m}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}：|f_{n}(x)|\geq\dfrac{1}{N}\right\}\right)=0,
\end{align*}
we are done.

Comment: *this* is Borel-Cantelli

Answer (score 7):

Another way, by Monotone Convergence Theorem or Tonelli:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n}|f_{n}|=\sum_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_{n}|\leq\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty,
\end{align*}
so for a.e. $x$, 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}|f_{n}(x)|<\infty,
\end{align*}
and hence $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: tnx, was my proof also correct?
You used borel cantelli lemma, right?

Comment: Not sure about the name of the theorem, just the fact that an integrable function is real-valued a.e.

Comment: You used the monotone convergence; that's worth mentioning.

Comment: It looks a beautiful answer.